# Popup-texts for images. Images aren't in a line

Tags: css

I am really new into creating websites, so
I am trying to make a css effect where a popup-text appears when someone hovers an image. I want to add more images for the popup into a row. So I tried to make an unordered list, but the problem is that those picture aren't in a row. They all are floating left and are below of the previous one. 
It would be nice if someone could fix it.
Here are the source codes:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainsection">
            <ul>
                <li><div class="boxcontainer">
                        <img id="margin" class="galleryZoom" src="images/reference/tropicalisland.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" />
                        <div class="bubbleposition">
                            <p>Tropical Island</p>
                        </div>
                    </div></li>

                    <li><div class="boxcontainer">
                        <img id="margin" class="galleryZoom" src="images/reference/gop-logo.png" />
                            <div class="bubbleposition">
                                <p>GOP Varieté Theater</p>
                            </div>
                        </div></li>

            </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.bubbleposition {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0; 
    color: #FFF;
    top: -200px;
    left: -1.65%; 
    width: 250px; 
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,30,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgba(255,255,255, .75);
    -webkit-transition: .5s; transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.boxcontainer .bubbleposition:after {
    position: relative; 
    top: 0%; 
    left: 10%; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 30, 0.5);
    white-space: nowrap; 
    color:#DDD;
}  
.boxcontainer:hover .bubbleposition {
    opacity: 1; 
    top: -270px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* Here is the problem | Should make list of pictures in a line */
#mainsection ul li .boxcontainer {
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is that you're trying to align the *contents* of the `<li>` tags. All you're doing in that case is aligning the stuff *within* something that's already out of alignment. What you actually want to do is align the `<li>` tags themselves. `display: inline;` sort of functions counter-intuitively as well, you actually want `display: inline-block;`

```
#mainsection ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0dbh9jws/1/) (make sure the window is wide enough for them to sit next to each other)

Even better, I'd prefer to use [floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float) in this situation.

```
#mainsection ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0dbh9jws)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean all images in a single row? If that's the case call display: inline for `<li>` instead of .boxcontainer

```
#mainsection ul li {
   display:inline;
}
```

or simply call

```
#mainsection ul li {
   float: left;
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You want the `li`s inline, it's useless to make the images.

```
#mainsection ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#mainsection ul li {
    float: left;
}
```